# Very weird print margin error, not follow custom margin

Tags: microsoft-excel, margins

My company recently got three new Dell PCs, all the same model, equipped with Windows 11 and Office 2021. One of our users needs to open an Excel file and print it. However, when they try to print, the margins come out wrong. The Excel file is set with a print area and custom margin of 1 cm. But when this user prints, the margin comes out as 1.9 cm, which is not what we want.

I've tried troubleshooting the issue:

- Adjusting the DPI resolution didn't work.
- Switching to the PLC 6 driver didn't work either.
- Printing only the selected area, fitting it to one page, aligning it to the center, and resetting the margin all failed to solve the problem.

What's strange is that when this user prints to PDF, the margin is still wrong, but it prints correctly for the other users. This leads me to believe that it's not a problem with the printer driver.

This issue is really frustrating me, and I'm considering reinstalling Windows and Office. Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this problem?

Comment: (1) Try it with running `excel /safe`. (2) Print margins may change automatically for the printer, so check the printer's settings. (3) Repair Office via *Control Panel > Programs and Features*, right-click and "Change". (4) Try the Excel advice in [this article](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-margins-not-printing-correctly/).

Comment: I found when I use print preview on this users' pc, I change margin, the preview not change accordingly. What make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to reinstall Windows.
You have to focus on removing drivers for printers and making the default settings for Excel software.
After that, I think the driver and Excel will be set to the default settings, and everything will be fine.
If it does not work, we can identify the problem from there.

Comment: Thanks, will try.